# What is the difference between clock_nanosleep and sleep_until?

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, c++03

I have been, for a while, successfully using the following scheme to put a thread to sleep for an amount of time given by `intervalMs`:

```
struct timespec tsCreate( long seconds, long nanoseconds )
{    /* Local variables. */
    struct  timespec  result ;

    seconds = (seconds < 0) ? 0 : seconds ;
    nanoseconds = (nanoseconds < 0) ? 0 : nanoseconds ;

    while (nanoseconds >= 1000000000L)
    {
        seconds++ ;  nanoseconds = nanoseconds - 1000000000L ;
    }

    result.tv_sec = seconds ;
    result.tv_nsec = nanoseconds ;

    return (result);
}

timespec tsCreateMs(long ms)
{
    // convert the
    return tsCreate( ms / 1000, ms * 1000000 );
}

timespec intervalMs = tsCreateMs( 50 );
alarm = tsAdd( alarm, intervalMs);

clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, TIMER_ABSTIME, &alarm, NULL);
```

Where alarm is a timespec specifying monotonic time and has been initialized at some time in the past, and the interval is some other interval timespec.  Recently, I began using a virtual machine to run some of my software, and while I haven't yet tested whether or the software is affected by the use of a virtual machine, I am finding that often times it appears that clock_nanosleep doesn't wake up in time.  This is made obvious by taking the time at the point where the interval is added to the alarm as:

```
struct timespec tsAdd( timespec  time1, timespec  time2)
{
    /* Local variables. */
    struct  timespec  result ;

    /* Add the two times together. */

    result.tv_sec = time1.tv_sec + time2.tv_sec ;
    result.tv_nsec = time1.tv_nsec + time2.tv_nsec ;
    if (result.tv_nsec >= 1000000000L)
    {       /* Carry? */
        result.tv_sec++ ;
        result.tv_nsec = result.tv_nsec - 1000000000L ;
    }
    return (result) ;
}

int tsCompare( struct  timespec  time1, struct  timespec  time2)
{
    if (time1.tv_sec < time2.tv_sec)
        return (-1) ;               /* Less than. */
    else if (time1.tv_sec > time2.tv_sec)
        return (1) ;                /* Greater than. */
    else if (time1.tv_nsec < time2.tv_nsec)
        return (-1) ;               /* Less than. */
    else if (time1.tv_nsec > time2.tv_nsec)
        return (1) ;                /* Greater than. */
    else
        return (0) ;                /* Equal. */
}

void wait()
{
  alarm = tsAdd( alarm, intervalMs);

  timespec now;
  clock_gettime( CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &timeNow );

  // tsCompare = timespec comparison function
  if ( tsCompare( now, alarm ) > 0 )
  {
    // tsShow displays formatted timespec
    printf( "TimeNow=%s   AlarmTime=%s\n", tsShow( now ), tsShow( alarm ) );
  }

  clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, TIMER_ABSTIME, &alarm, NULL);
}
```

Where I will sporadically find that the print statement is printed.

This function is used in a thread which is required to operate on a precise interval.  The usage of this appears as such:

```
void run()
{

  Interval interval;
  interval.setIntervalMs( 20 );

  for (;;)
  {
     //do some stuff here
     interval.wait();   //< Where this calls the function as shown above
  }
}
```

I thoroughly examined all of the functions in the `for` loop and found that no function exceeded the `intervalMs` time.

I have since switched to using the following:

```
void wait()
{
  // alarm is a std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock>
  // interval is a std::chrono::milliseconds
  alarm += interval;
  std::this_thread::sleep_until( alarm );
}
```

And I have found the clock to be far more accurate, as in, there are far less times where it will report that it has overstepped its anticipated wake up time.

While I have to maintain the software due to backwards compatibility issues, can anyone explain to me what the real difference is between these two methods.  If they are both supposed to theoretically draw from monotonic time, how can I have different results?

Comment: What is the definition of `tsAdd` and `tsCompare`?

Comment: @HowardHinnant  added to the appropriate code section

Comment: So `Interval` has an implicit conversion to `timespec`?  It is hard to read code I can't see.

Comment: This is completely normal. You cannot expect time-shared, modern, commodity OSs to give you exact nanosecond-precision scheduling. Unless you're seeing weird things like wakeups hundreds of milliseconds late, you need to work around it, not try to avoid it. Or, if you really need that level of timing precision, you should be working on specialised hardware with specialised control software,

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I have seen wakeups around 150 ms after the intended target.  I wasn't expecting millisecond precision, but hoping for around 10 ms precision.  What I'm seeing is far from this.  The timing plays into filtering algorithms which rely, when unsimulated, on outside stimuli that can have variable intervals, thus simply saying that delta time is a certain value is insufficient when physical time constants can exceed this value, thus the time has to be measurable.  Is better timing achievable by directly utilizing kernel timers or is this redundant when regarding sleep_until?

Comment: `sleep_until` is very likely built on top of the timers that the OS provides.  The advantage of `sleep_until` is that it catches errors such as unintended units conversions at compile-time.  So it could be that there is a subtle logic error in your `clock_gettime` version that is eliminated in your `sleep_until` version.  However I can't see enough code to confirm that theory.

Comment: @AlexBaum 15ms is the very minimum I'd expect, just based on threading time slices. Then you have to compete with processor time and everything else. 150ms still seems "normal", albeit on the high and undesirable side. 500ms you start to complain. 1-2s you have a problem. Sleeps in this context should only ever be considered a "sleep until _at least_ this time". Unless you're writing a kernel driver, you need to compensate by measurement; you won't beat the reliability you're getting. That's just the trade-off we make to have multiprocess, multi-purpose computers.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings  Thanks for setting that straight.  I'll just have to live with what I've got.